# Sending an ALERT using ODS in SAS

Tags: sas

I'm trying to send an alert only if a macro variable value is not 0 and another alert all times, both in same script.

I want to send this only if variable value is not 0.

```
filename myfile1 email To=&ToAddress
subject="ALERT for &tday." TYPE="text/html";
ODS LISTING CLOSE;
ODS HTML BODY=myfile1 style=BarrettsBlue;
OPTIONS NOCENTER LINESIZE=256;

Proc print data=Counts_6days noobs label;
title "monitoring by Score Date";
run;
ODS html close;
ods listing;
```

I want to send this all times.

```
filename myfile email To=&ToAddress
subject="monitoring for &tday." CONTENT_TYPE="text/html";

ODS LISTING CLOSE;
ODS HTML BODY=myfile style=BarrettsBlue;
OPTIONS NOCENTER LINESIZE=256;

Proc print data=COUNTS noobs label;
title "monitoring by Score Date";
run;

ODS HTML CLOSE;
ODS LISTING;
```

Comment: Hi Sampath_T, your question is not clear.  What are you having difficulty figuring out?  Are you asking how to conditionally execute code?

Comment: @Gerard-de-visser [tag:ods] is not for SAS ODS but for the Open Document Spreadsheet format.  SAS ODS is the Output Delivery System, which is what you use to create non-basic text output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SAS conditional macro statements need to be wrapped in a macro. For example:

```
%macro example(arg);
    %if &arg. ~= 0 %then %do;
        /* Your conditional code here */
    %end;
%mend example;
%let var = 0;
%example(&var.)
```

This code creates a [macro](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/61885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#macro-stmt.htm) called `%example` which expects one parameter. The macro is called with `%example()`, at which point it evaluates the code inside the macro. The [`%if %then %do; %end;`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/61885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000543542.htm) block allows you to choose whether some code is run or not based upon whether the condition evaluates to true or false.

In your case you could wrap your first block in a macro similar to this, while leaving the second block outside.